# NSAttributedString: Spacing between bullet and text

Tags: html, ios, nsattributedstring, core-text, nsparagraphstyle

I'm creating textviews with an html document that I'm loading with `[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:`

There are many unordered lists (`<UL>`) in the HTML document. I cannot find a way to reduce the space between bullets in an unordered list and their subsequent text.

- *<-this space->* TEXT ABC
- *<-this space->* TEXT DEF
- *<-this space->* TEXT GHI JKLM NOP JKLM NOP JKLM NOPJ KLM NOPJ KLM NOP JKLM NOPJ KLM NOP JKLM NOPJ KLM NOP
- *<-this space->* TEXT QRS

When I reduce the space between bullets with CSS, it shows up when the doc is viewed as a webpage but the changes are not reflected in the NSAttributed strings in the app.